# Bash - turn off monitor mode by default

Tags: bash, shell

In bash, `set +m` is supposed to turn off the monitor mode.  I would like this to be the default behaviour, and put the line in the `.bashrc`

The `.bashrc` file is read (put a line `echo "hello"` next to it), but the notifications for terminated jobs still appear.  Why is that?

Comment: Interesting. `set -o` even claims `monitor off`, but `set +m` afterwards actually changes the behavior.

Comment: This should be the default. You could add `set -m` to ~/.bashrc, but it doesnt take. You would have to add it to PROMPT_COMMAND ..https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395963/bash-set-m-option-does-not-work-when-placed-in-the-bashrc-file

Answer (score 4):

Because job notifications are tied to interactive mode, not monitor mode. The description of what `set -m` does is quite misleading. It has a number of effects such as forcing pipelines to run in their own process group, and causes traps on CHLD to trigger for each background process. It doesn't actually do anything to affect whether "job control" works. You can still use all the job related commands and refer to jobs using jobspecs even with `set +m`, so long as your OS supports job control.

The same applies to ksh. I'm not aware of any way to disable or hide job notifications. If Bash is started with interactive mode you will always see them, even if you subsequently `set +i` (which AFAICT has no effect after startup). I find `set +b` makes things slightly more tolerable. If you're writing a script that makes use of job control for fancy multi-processing then you won't have to worry about it anyway.